# Wilson's theorem and gcd

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

If $n$ is composite, $gcd(n,(n−1)!+1) = 1$

I know Wilson's theorem states $(n-1)!\equiv -1 (mod $ $n)$. That gives me $(n-1)! +1 \equiv 0 (mod $ $n)$. Why is the gcd = 1?

Comment: Because if $p$ is a prime divisor of $n$ and $p<n$ then $1<p\leqslant n-1$ so $p\mid(n-1)!$ so...

Comment: @CarlosIsraelJrl could you please elaborate? I'm new to this and still confused. If $(n−1)!+1≡0(mod$ $n)$, Doesn't that show $n|(n-1)!+1$?

Comment: @user363877 Wilson's theorem does **not** state $(n-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod n$.  Why do you say it does?

Comment: @ErickWong https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem

Comment: @user363877, only for prime $n$.

Comment: @user363877 Wilson's theorem states precisely when $(n-1)!\equiv -1 \pmod n$ is true.  It is a full sentence with a conditional clause, not just an equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that, if $n$ is composite and not the square of a prime, there exist positive integers $a,b,a\neq b$ such that

$$ab=n\mathrm{\ and\ } a,b<n$$

Thus, since $ab|(n-1)!$, we get that

$$n|(n-1)!$$

If $n=p^2$ with $p$ an odd prime, we have that $2p<n$, and thus

$$n|2p^2|(n-1)!$$

In either case, we get that

$$(n-1)!+1 = kn+1$$

for some positive integer $k$. We seek to find

$$\gcd(n,kn+1)$$

Assume for the sake of contradiction that this $\gcd$ is not $1$. Then there exists a prime $p$ such that

$$p|n,p|kn+1$$

$$p|kn,|kn+1$$

$$p|1$$

However, no primes divide one, and

$$\gcd(n,(n-1)!+1) = 1$$

If $n=4$, we have $\gcd(n,(n-1)!+1) = \gcd(4,7)=1$.

If $n=p$ is prime, Wilson's Theorem states that

$$(p-1)!\equiv -1\mod p$$

so $$p|(p-1)!+1$$ and $$\gcd(p,(p-1)!+1) = p$$

Comment: $4$ is composite, however $4\nmid3!.$

Comment: @CarlosIsraelJrl that is the only exception https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem

Comment: @CarlosIsraelJrl You're right  - I forgot to account for the squares of primes.

Comment: can you explain  $n | 2p^2 $

Comment: @user363877 If $n=p^2$ as supposed, we have that $p^2|2p^2$.

Comment: That $(n,kn+1)=1$ follows instantaneously from Euclid's algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ is composite then every prime divisor $p\mid n$ satisfies $p<n$, hence $p\mid (n-1)!$.  It follows that $p \nmid (n-1)!+1$.  So $n$ and $(n-1)!+1$ have no primes in common.